# React JS TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined at areHookInputsEqual

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, server-side-rendering, react-dom, react-dom-server

I am facing some errors while rendering at SSR for some URL using **renderToString** from **"react-dom/server"**

I am getting following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at areHookInputsEqual (C:\projects\spd-web-app1\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:992:38)
at Object.useMemo (C:\projects\spd-web-app1\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:1230:13)
at useMemo (C:\projects\spd-web-app1\node_modules\react\cjs\react.development.js:1521:21)
at Provider (C:\projects\spd-web-app1\node_modules\react-redux\lib\components\Provider.js:22:41)
at finishHooks (C:\projects\spd-web-app1\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:1077:16)
at processChild (C:\projects\spd-web-app1\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:3046:14)
at resolve (C:\projects\spd-web-app1\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:2962:5)
at ReactDOMServerRenderer.render (C:\projects\spd-web-app1\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:3437:22)
at ReactDOMServerRenderer.read (C:\projects\spd-web-app1\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:3375:29)
at renderToString (C:\projects\spd-web-app1\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:3990:27)
```

What i found is,in **react-dom-server.node.development.js** → **createWorkInProgressHook()**

I am getting below object, in which **memoizedState** is not an array.

```
{
  memoizedState: 0,
  queue: { last: null, dispatch: [Function: bound dispatchAction] },
  next: {
    memoizedState: { current: [QueryData] },
    queue: null,
    next: { memoizedState: [Object], queue: null, next: [Object] }
  }
}
```

which when used in **useMemo()**
`var prevDeps = prevState[1];`
will return undefined and thus causing issue in **areHookInputsEqual()**

I am not sure what could have gone wrong, so do not have a code to share.

Comment: Can you include your useMemo code? It looks like based on the error, you aren't setting the dependency array as an array (likely the undefined value you mentioned previously)

Answer (score 3):

I've seen this happening when a hook was using after a conditional statement.
Moving the hook usage above the conditional statement fixed the problem.

Reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

Comment: Don't have any such issue, still it is giving me the same error.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is really old, but hopefully posting this can help someone else in the future. In my situation, I got this error when I used Array.map() without specifying a unique `key` attribute on the top-level child element in the loop.

It took me days to figure out my mistake, and for whatever reason, there was no clear error message indicating the root cause. It's clear in the docs that a unique key should be used on all child items of a list, but I don't think that's a very good reason to allow such a cryptic error message to surface.

https://react.dev/learn/rendering-lists#keeping-list-items-in-order-with-key

Comment: You're a life saver, thanks! I had forgotten to set the key to items inside a select component. There were no warnings about it in the console, only this cryptic error that had nothing to do with that. Thanks again!